# Laravel: Attempt to read property "customer_name" on bool

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to laravel. I have to edit a form that contains a dropdown list. Edit form works fine works without the dropdown input. Updating with dropdown input throws the above error.

controller:

```
 public function edit(QR_details $qR_detail)
    {
        return view('pages.edit_QR_details')->with('qr_details', $qR_detail);
    }

public function update(Request $request, QR_details $qR_details)
    {
        $qR_details->update($request->all());
        toastr()->success('QR Detail updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route(('QR_code_details.index'));
    }
```

Edit form:

```
form action="{{ route('QR_code_details.update', $qr_details->id) }}" method="POST" class="">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method("PATCH")
                                    <div class="px-3 form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group p-2 col-5">
                                        <label for="" class="form-label  fw-bold text-secondary">Customer Name*</label>
                                        <select name="customer_name" class="form-select shadow" name="" id="">
                                            @foreach ($qr_details as $qr_detail)
                                            <option value="{{ $qr_detail->customer_name }}">{{ $qr_detail->customer_name }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="form-group p-2 col-6">
                                        <label for="" class="form-label text-secondary fw-bold">Background Image</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="background image" class="form-control shadow" value="{{ $qr_details->background_image }}">
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group p-2 col-6">
                                        <label for="" class="form-label text-secondary fw-bold">Create QR Code</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="create_qr_code" class="form-control shadow" value="{{ $qr_details->create_qr_code }}">
                                    </div>
    
                                    <div class="form-group p-2 col-6">
                                        <label for="" class="form-label text-secondary fw-bold">Movable QR</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="movable_qr" class="form-control shadow" value="{{ $qr_details->maovable_qr }}">
                                    </div>
    
                                   
                                    <div class="row ">
                                        <div class="mt-4 col">
                                            <button class="btn bg-gradient-danger btn-sm btn-rounded">Cancel</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class=" col mt-4">
                                            <button class="btn bg-gradient-success btn-sm btn-rounded">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('QR_code_detail_edit-{qR_detail}', [QRDetailsController::class, 'edit'])->name('QR_code_details.edit');
    Route::post('QR_code_detail_edit-{qR_detail}', [QRDetailsController::class, 'update'])->name('QR_code_details.update');
```

Can someone help me out, how it should be done ?

Comment: `@foreach ($qr_details as $qr_detail)` - You're looping over a single `QR_details` Model, which makes `$qr_detail` a `boolean` in that iteration, and `(true/false)->customer_name` is not valid. I'm not sure what you're _trying_ to do, but you should never loop over a single Model; all that does is loops the various `public` properties of the Model, which doesn't make sense as `<option>` elements.

Comment: Can you print out `$qr_details` this seems like a single model to me, hence  some attribute could be a boolean?

Comment: @Aless55 You're 100% correct: `QR_details $qR_detail` loads a single Model implicitly from the `id` in the URL (like `/qr-details/1`, etc.), while `->with('qr_details', $qR_detail);` sends that single Model instance to the view as the variable `$qr_details`, which is then being iterated (which is generally a mistake, but does have some use cases) 

Comment: @TimLewis  this works fine for add form but I tried the same way for edit form which doesn't work and no idea what to be done

Comment: That's fine, but what does this _do_ on the create form? Probably nothing. If you're looping over `$QR_details` on the `Create` form, there is nothing to loop over; the model hasn't been created yet. That `<select>` element would have no `<option>`s available on `create`. I'll ask again, what are you trying to do with that `<select>` element? The way you have it written makes zero sense.

Comment: iterating a Model instance returns its 'public' properties (like any object) ... that boolean will be there for any Model instance, existing or not ... you could call `toArray` on the model to get an array you can iterate over of the attributes and any relationships loaded if you would like